# "that is" in the sense of "to be specific"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

> Looking at the information in more detail, for every 100 million PMT, 76 incidents took place on a bus in 2002, resulting in 66 injuries correspondingly. The same number of incidents can also be seen when we look at the figures for light rail, but there were only 39 injuries recorded in these cases. Meanwhile, commuter rail passengers were least likely to experience problems, **that is**, only 20 incidents and 17 injuries occurred on commuter services.

I use **that is** in the above paragraph to mean **to be more specific**. However, I'm not sure **that is** delivers that meaning properly here. Does it? If it doesn't, what other phrases would you recommend?

Answer (score 5):

Your interpretation of the meaning of *that is* is similar to sense (a).  [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/that-is#google_vignette) defines the phrase:

> **that is** in British English
> a. to be precise
> b. in other words
> c. for example

However, your proposed use of the phrase is not so appropriate.

We use *that is* to introduce further explanations of things already fairly sufficiently said.  In your example,

> Meanwhile, commuter rail passengers were least likely to experience problems, **that is**, only 20 incidents and 17 injuries occurred on commuter services.

the first clause does not sufficiently state the situation.

On the other hand, if we give sufficient details in the first clause, *that is* would phase in smoothly:

> Meanwhile, commuter rail passengers were least likely to experience problems **as the  incident and injury figures of this mode are only about a quarter of the bus's**, *that is*, only 20 incidents and 17 injuries occurred on commuter services.

If we choose not to elaborate on the first clause, we could restructure the sentence incorporating **as**, as described in Edmond's  answer.

Edit to Incorporate a Comment

*as* has the meaning of **because**: see [sense A2 under conjunction](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as).

Comment: Could you tell me what exactly does **as** mean here?

Comment: *as* has the meaning of **because**.  Please see [sense A2 under conjunction](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you wrote is fine. (And I can vouch that "that is" can mean "to be precise" in American as well as British English.)

Other possible options:

> Meanwhile, commuter rail passengers were least likely to experience problems: only 20 incidents and 17 injuries occurred on commuter services.

or

> Meanwhile, commuter rail passengers were least likely to experience problems. In particular, only 20 incidents and 17 injuries occurred on commuter services.

Comment: As an American English speaker, I would say that the phrasing in the original question is not glaringly wrong, but not quite on target either (for the reasons @Seowjooheng stated). Mark's suggested options are better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could replace ***that is*** with ***as***:

> Meanwhile, commuter rail passengers were least likely to experience problems, as only 20 incidents and 17 injuries occurred on commuter services.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).